# Remove characters from a string in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Most of programming languages have `substring` or equivalent. I'm looking for a way to do this in Visualforce.
My requirement is adding a link to show a popup(show/hide div) to display a comment field which is some what lengthy. The content of the hyper link should be first 10 characters of the same comment field.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showNote('{!item.comment}');">{!item.comment}</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done with `LEFT` page variable function.

```
<a href="#" onclick="showNote('{!item.comment}');">{!LEFT(item.comment,10)}</a>
```

There some other important page variable functions also out there in salesforce as described [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_functions.htm).